# Merge two hashes in order to create a json file

Tags: ruby

Hi I want to merge two hashes into a json file which should look like this:

```
{
 "name": "MS Suite",
 "version": "2017.1.0",
 "components": [
  {
   "code": "1x.2017",
   "name": "microservice1",
   "version": "1.1.3-1"
  },
  {
   "code": "3x.2017",
   "name": "microservice2",
   "version": "1.1.15-1"
  }
 ]
}
```

Please find below hash1:

```
{
 "name": "MS Suite",
 "version": "2017.1.0"
}
```

Please find below hash2 which is an array:

```
[
 {
  "code": "1x.2017",
  "name": "microservice1",
  "version": "1.1.3-1"
 },
 {
  "code": "3x.2017",
  "name": "microservice2",
  "version": "1.1.15-1"
 }
]
```

Comment: The description is backwards as I understand :)

Comment: please, try to read some _basic_ documentation about it before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Hash#`[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D):

```
hash = {
  "name": "MS Suite",
  "version": "2017.1.0"
}


array = [
  {
    "code": "1x.2017",
    "name": "microservice1",
    "version": "1.1.3-1"
  },
  {
    "code": "3x.2017",
    "name": "microservice2",
    "version": "1.1.15-1"
  }
]

hash['components'] = array
hash
#=> {:name=>"MS Suite", :version=>"2017.1.0", "components"=>[{:code=>"1x.2017", :name=>"microservice1", :version=>"1.1.3-1"}, {:code=>"3x.2017", :name=>"microservice2", :version=>"1.1.15-1"}]}
```

To convert it to json:

```
require 'json'
hash.to_json
#=> "{\"name\":\"MS Suite\",\"version\":\"2017.1.0\",\"components\":[{\"code\":\"1x.2017\",\"name\":\"microservice1\",\"version\":\"1.1.3-1\"},{\"code\":\"3x.2017\",\"name\":\"microservice2\",\"version\":\"1.1.15-1\"}]}"
```